# c++ question, about * and ->

Tags: c++

when I have a pointer like:

```
MyClass * pRags = new MyClass;
```

So i can use

```
pRags->foo()
```

or

```
(*pRags).foo()
```

to call foo.

Why these 2 are identical? and what is *pRags?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pRags->foo()` is **defined** as syntactic sugar that is equivalent to `(*pRags).foo()`.

the `*` operator dereferences a pointer.  That is, it says that you're operating on what the pointer points to, not the pointer itself.

Answer (score 5):

> Why are these two identical?

They are equivalent because the spec says they are equivalent.  The built-in `->` is defined in terms of the built-in `*` and `.`.

> What is `*pRags`?

It is the `MyClass` object pointed to by `pRags`.  The `*` *dereferences* the pointer, yielding the pointed-to object.

For more information, consider picking up [a good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, the '->' is there for convenience.  Dereferencing a pointer to an object every time you access a class variable for function is quite ugly, inconvenient, and potentially more confusing.

For instance:

```
(*(*(*car).engine).flux_capacitor).init()
```

vs

```
car->engine->flux_capacitor->init()
```

Comment: I like the example.  It certainly clarifies the *reason* for this shortcut.

Comment: You got the first example wrong. `(*(*(*car).engine).flux_capacitor).init()`

Answer (score 2):

The `->` is just a convenient way to write `(*).`. and `*pRags` is the object at the address stored in `pRags`.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes they are identical. `->` was included in C (and thus inherited into C++) as a notational convenience.
- `*` in that context is used to dereference a pointer.

Comment: the questions was *why* they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Unary `*` is known as the [dereferencing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator). Dereferencing a pointer turns a `T*` into a `T&`; dereferencing an object invokes that object type's unary `operator*` on that object value if one is defined, or gives an error otherwise.

Comment: Does it turn it into `T&`?  Into a *reference* to `T`?  Or does it return the actual value?  I'm not sure there's a difference, except that `T&` is always valid, whereas `T*` may point to `NULL`, and thus be invalid.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman : Yes, it turns into a reference to `T` rather than a `T` value; otherwise `*pdouble = 4.2;` would fail to work as it would be attempting to assign a value to an rvalue. The act of dereferencing a `NULL` pointer invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but I don't see how that pertains to this.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  However, considering that it works the same in C, and C doesn't have references, I'm not sure you're correct.  In C you can use it as an lvalue too.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman : In C, unary `operator*` yields an lvalue of the object at the pointed-to address. In C++ we call that a reference. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

`(*pRags)` that goes through the pointer `pRags` and get you whole object, so on that you could use regular dot notation `.` .

Answer (score 1):

*pRags is a pointer of type MyClass. Just like you can have pointers for primitive data types, e.g.  int* ptr, you can also have pointers to objects and in this case represented by pRags. Now accessing the object "members" is done using the arrow operator (->) or you can use the "." and dereference "*" to access the object's member values. Here a member is a variable inside MyClass. So, foo() would have a definition inside MyClass.